# What is the meaning of this sentence with "degenerating into mere arbitrariness" in it?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I checked the meaning of "arbitrariness" which says the meaning is "the quality of being based on random choice or personal whim, rather than any reason or system."

But I don't think I could make out the essence of the statement. So please help me.

> In fact, freedom is in danger of degenerating into **mere arbitrariness** unless it is lived in terms of responsibleness.

Excerpt From: Viktor E. Frankl. “Man's Search for Meaning.” Apple Books.

Comment: Kim, with all due respect, I don't think we are going to be able to keep answering these open-ended questions from you on this book. I think you might have to ponder this book yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that one has no principles controlling one's actions. Then the actions will be "free" in a negative sense: they may be arbitrary and change with the whim of the moment.

If one acts according to principles which themselves are chosen freely and responsibly, then their actions will be free, but not arbitrary.

Comment: Who defines what is 'responsible'?

Comment: If there is freedom, "responsible" is defined by the individual. Anyway, I think that's what Frankl was saying. For me, it all gets circular pretty quickly.

Comment: The dividing line between 'freedom' and 'licence' was something that bothered my father.